# What is the location of chrome in a Linux machine?

Tags: node.js, linux, google-chrome

I have an node app which needs to know that location of chrome in your machine. Different platforms have chrome installed on different locations. For example - I am doing this for Windows and Mac.

```
import os from 'os';

export default function getPlatform() {
  if (os.platform() === "win32") {
    return 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
  } else if (os.platform() === "darwin") {
    return '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome'
  } else {
    return 'PLEASE ENTER CHROME.exe LOCATION HERE'
  }
}
```

I want to add support for Linux here, so, I want to know where Chrome app gets installed on a Linux machine

Answer (score 1):

On my machine (Xubuntu 20.04) it's `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`, but that might be different in other distros.
There is a symbolic link from `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` to  `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`, I think that is your best bet.

Comment: So, I should use "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome" for linux platform, is what you're suggesting?

Comment: I would rather use /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable, but it's best to collect a few more infos from users of other distros. Please keep in mind that some Linux users do not use the full  Google Chrome, but rather Chromium (the open source variant of Chrome). Supporting them as well might take some additional effort.